# Removing a set from a list if found

Tags: python

I have the following code, where it acts strange:

```
teamed = [{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 7}, {8, 6}, {9, 13}, {10, 14}]
game_3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14]
combi = [set(combo) for combo in itertools.combinations(game_3, 2)]
for c in combi:
    if c in teamed:
        combi.remove(c)
        
print(combi)
```

I wanted to remove any occurrences of any set that is in `teamed` from `combi`, but strangely `{1,3}` was not removed and when i tried to use 'print(c)' after the for loop i found out it doesn`t loop over '{1,3}'.

The result I get is like this, however `{1,3}` is already in `teamed`, and it was not removed from `combi`:

```
[{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {8, 1}, {1, 11}, {1, 12}, {1, 13}, {1, 14}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {8, 2}, {2, 11}, {2, 12}, {2, 13}, {2, 14}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {8, 3}, {11, 3}, {3, 12}, {3, 13}, {3, 14}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {8, 4}, {11, 4}, {4, 12}, {4, 13}, {4, 14}, {5, 7}, {8, 5}, {11, 5}, {12, 5}, {13, 5}, {5, 14}, {6, 7}, {11, 6}, {12, 6}, {13, 6}, {6, 14}, {11, 7}, {12, 7}, {13, 7}, {14, 7}, {8, 11}, {8, 12}, {8, 13}, {8, 14}, {11, 13}, {11, 14}, {12, 13}, {12, 14}, {13, 14}]
```

Comment: As you have found, removing things from a list as you iterate over it can cause problems.

Comment: Also note a set of frozensets would be more efficient in terms of containment testing (`x in y` is O(1), rather than a list's O(n)).

Comment: There is one more problem in your code. You are missing `9,10` in the `game_3` list. So you cannot get all the combinations present in `teamed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have eluded in the comments, editing a list that you are actively looping over can create problems, a simple solution is to append all values not in 'teamed' to a new list, for example:

```
import itertools

new_list = []

teamed = [{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 7}, {8, 6}, {9, 13}, {10, 14}]
game_3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14]
combi = [set(combo) for combo in itertools.combinations(game_3, 2)]
for c in combi:
    if c not in teamed:
        new_list.append(c)

print(new_list)
```

Let me know if this achieves what you're aiming for.